# How to combine two columns in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-algebra

I have a query of the form

```
select member.first_name||' '||member.last_name as member_name
from member
MINUS
select distinct member.first_name||' '||member.last_name as member_name
from member,borrow_record
where member.id = borrow_record.member_id
```

I think the relational algebra expression of this query would be something like

```
π(member.first_name,member.last_name)(member) - π(member.first_name,member.last_name)(σ(member.id = borrow_record.member_id)(member ⨯ borrow_record))
```

but i dont know how to combine the two columns named first_name and last_name

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give definitions & a reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "convert"--Same result? Same structure? Nested RA calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can, even if you are not actually running code. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. PS What exact assignment were you given? PS "combining" strings that way is a string operation not a relation operation; know what string operators you have & where you can use calls to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's a logic error in your SQL. Two distinct `member` records might have distinct `first_name` and distinct `last_name`, but end up with the same concatenated `member_name`.

You (presumably) want your query to return the name of members who have no record of borrowing. Your code doesn't reliably achieve that. Instead, the `MINUS` should apply between `select member.first_name, member.last_name`, as indeed your RA code does.

> i dont know how to combine the two columns named first_name and last_name [in relational algebra]

The short answer: combining string columns is not the job of an algebra.

As @philipxy points out there are many varieties of RA. They have operators for restricting and combining relation values. Most of them don't have field-level operators even for arithmetic between columns, let alone string handling.

Codd 1972 (the earliest design for a form of RA) did not expect the algebra to include domain-specific operations (where his 'domain' roughly corresponds to modern 'type' in programming languages). Instead a query would feed its results to some conventional programming language, for further manipulation.